# Add “Back" button on ExoPlayer Controller View

Tags: android, uiviewcontroller, exoplayer

I have ExoPlayer on an activity.
How can I add “Back” button into controller view to let user go back to the previous activity? Any help are really welcome.

Comment: How do you starting ExoPlayer Activity. and if there is `onBackPreseed()` is overridden that you can call super class's `onBackPressed()` It will be helpful if you show you activity's code.

Comment: Thank you. However I have found the solution. I will post bellow.

Answer (score 3):

First, to customize the layout of `SimpleExoPlayerView` throughout your app, or just for certain configurations, you can define `exo_playback_control_view.xml` layout file in your application `res/layout` directories. These layouts will override the one provided by the `ExoPlayer` library, and will be inflated for use by `SimpleExoPlayerView`.

In `exo_playback_control_view.xml`, you can try with mine:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="#CC000000"

    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_hide"
            android:id="@+id/exo_controller"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:text="Back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="26dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>
   
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This class provide some common controllers for exoplayer and one more button with id “btn_back”. You can `findBindId` in your activity then add whatever event you want, something like `this.finish()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Add below code into your main layout like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.**

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ry_player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible">
    
            <com.potyvideo.library.AndExoPlayerView
                android:id="@+id/andExoPlayerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:andexo_aspect_ratio="aspect_match"
                app:andexo_full_screen="true"
                app:andexo_play_when_ready="false"
                app:andexo_resize_mode="Fit" />
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ry_course_iv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="#66000000"
                android:visibility="visible">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_thumb"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly_back"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="17dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_back" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: very nice..

Thanks